# What's the difference between collision and probe length in a hash table?How to keep track of them?

Tags: python, hash, linear-probing

Hi I'm new to Python and i implemented a hash table class which resolves collisions with linear probing.

Now I'm trying to write a function to keep track of the number of collisions and the probe length.I've written the function to keep track of the number of collisions but I have no idea how to keep track of the probe length because I thought they are the same?

```
def getCollisionAndProbeLength(self, key, value):
    position = self.hash_value(key)
    collision=0
    probeLength=0

    for i in range(self.table_size):
        if self.array[position] is None || self.array[position][0]==key && self.array[position][1]==value :#correct item or collision resolved
            break
        elif self.array[position][0]==key && self.array[position][1]!=value:
            collision+=1
            position = (position+1) % self.table_size
 return [collision,probeLength]
```

EDIT:
Okay apparently a collision means the position given by hash(key) is already occupied. Probe length is how many tries do you do *after that* until you find a position (in open addressing).

So I'm guessing it should be this:

```
 elif self.array[position][0]==key && self.array[position][1]!=value:
            collision+=1
            probeLength=collision-1
            position = (position+1) % self.table_size
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay apparently A collision means the position given by hash(key) is already occupied. Probe length is how many tries do you do *after that* until you find a position (in open addressing).